# Sprite won't move with finger/ SpriteKit / Swift 3

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

*I searched most places and could not find a "basic solution" to my question

Hi there, I am trying to create a simple SKSpriteNode that will move along with my finger anywhere on the screen (x & y coords). So far what I have done is the code below, and I can't seem to figure out much else because my Sprite won't even move when the game is ran. I am also getting an error at:

```
simpleS = self.childNode(withName: "simpleS") as! SKSpriteNode
```

This line of code causes my program to not run since I've added it. Please and thanks for your help.

**In this case Sprite "simpleS" is the Sprite I am trying to move when touches begin.**

***CODE STARTS HERE:***

```
    import SpriteKit
    import GameplayKit

    class GameScene: SKScene {

var simpleS = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    simpleS = self.childNode(withName: "simpleS") as! SKSpriteNode

    simpleS.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
}



override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        simpleS.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 0.0))
        simpleS.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: location.y, duration: 0.0))

    }

}
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        simpleS.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 0.0))
        simpleS.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: location.y, duration: 0.0))

    }
      }
    }
```

Comment: There are several issues with this code. Try following a guide like this for getting more up to speed with SpriteKit; https://www.raywenderlich.com/49721/how-to-create-a-breakout-game-using-spritekit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code

```
simpleS = self.childNode(withName: "simpleS") as! SKSpriteNode
```

connects the sprites in your GameScene.sks with GameScene.swift
so in the first step you have to make sure that you set the right name (exactly "simpleS") in your sks file.

if you did it right, so please send the error for us.
i have built and ran your code and everything works in a right way.

another point is that if you want your sprites only moves by your finger movement you have to delete the codes in touchesBegan function, because touchesBegan moves your sprite wherever you touch.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/a499ed44c710c13895ee0800ed8754f0 This is the error I'm getting, so weird. Not sure what I am doing wrong, thanks for the help.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working! Turns out I named the background "simpleS" and not the actual node...Anyways thanks for your help!